# How can I get vendor folder from docker container?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code

I have Dockerfile

```
FROM golang:latest

ARG gopath=/go/src

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y go-dep

RUN mkdir $gopath/chat
ADD . $gopath/chat
WORKDIR $gopath/chat

RUN dep ensure
RUN cd chat && go install chat

CMD ["go", "run", "main.go"]
```

I build and run container with commands:

```
docker build -t chat .
docker run -p 8000:80 chat
```

In my IDE(Visual Studio Code) I want to see code from vendor folder, but it in docker container. How can I see code from vendor folder in my IDE?

Comment: one way to remove `ADD` from your dockerfile and mount host location like . `docker run -v #PWD/hostapplication:/$gopath/chat -p 8000:80 chat`,second way is to use `docker cp contianer:$gopath/chat /host_path`

Comment: What benefit are you getting from trying to run this workflow in Docker?  I'd just install the Go toolchain on my host and not use Docker at this point in the process.